# Retrieving the verification code from an SMS into a textfield in Xcode 12.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am asking this question because none of the answers in the related questions here in SO resolves our issue. We have our textfield's Content Type set to "One Time Code". We even set the Keyboard Type to "Number Pad". The message received contains this text: `xxx is your verification code`. But the textfield is not picking up the code. It should be a simple setup but clearly we're missing something.

We're on Xcode 12.2.

Comment: Retrieving the verification code from an SMS into a textfield is not supported. Did you mean displaying the code in the auto-complete suggestions bar above the keyboard? This should be achieved by setting "One Time Code" as you have described.

Comment: On which device and iOS version you are testing?

Comment: Check AutoFill passwords under `Settings -> Passwords` make sure it's ON _(not sure if it can cause a problem, but at least you can try)_

Answer (score 0):

I never used it but I found this in apple documentation :
[oneTimeCode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/2980930-onetimecode)

```
// for a textfield set the textContentType :
singleFactorCodeTextField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
```

Comment: That is the same as setting the property in the Storyboard. I've mentioned we already did that: We have our textfield's Content Type set to "One Time Code". Anyway, we also tried that before and it did not help, got the same behavior.